# Can't retrieve enum after being stored as string in database

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, enums

I wanted to store the `String` value of my enum in the database, so I used:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private EducationType educationType;
```

But now when I try to read it out of the database, it gives me

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No enum constant enums.EducationType.Enum value etc; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant enums.EducationType.Enum value etc] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant enums.EducationType.Enum value etc
        at java.base/java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:240) ~[na:na]
```

Since the conversion **into** the database was automatically done by the annotation, how do I reverse it back into my model?

Enum looks something like:

```
enum EducationType {
A("apple"),
B("banana"),
C("cherry");
}
```

Banana was stored in the database through the @Enumerated annotation and can't be parsed back automatically it seems.

Comment: Check your database. What's stored there? Also edit your post and add the content of EducationType.

Comment: Also you might've stored the enums by their ordinal before adding the String enum type.

Comment: I didn't because it says that no `enum` exists of `enum.stringvalue`. In my db it is stored as `character varying (255)`

Comment: What is the value of educationType that is stored in database?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like enum value stored in database is not present in your code that’s why on mapping JPA entity with Table, exception is coming.

For example - if EducationType value is **Online** in database then same value should present in your code inside enum like

enum EducationType{
Online, Offline
}

Comment: Yes but now it's enum EducationType { A("string"), B("string") } and I stored "string" in the database which can't be parsed back automatically with the annotation.

Comment: If you want to map enum with table column then you have to store A/B in database. You can use value of enum later in your code.

Comment: I wanted to store the string value because it looks nicer in the database, but I guess I have no choice but to use the ordinal value.

Comment: Ok, Then I will suggest better not to use enum. You can map table column with String type in entity class.